# Theoretical concept of adding constraints to a VAR?

Tags: vector-autoregression

I was wondering whether someone can explain why one would add constraints to a VAR model. Recommendations to books / articles explaining these concepts in detail are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The starting point is, why would one expect that an *unrestricted* VAR model is necessarily a better approximation to a data generating process than a *restricted* VAR model?

It is certainly possible to think of real-world feedback systems between variables where feedback goes only one way (example 1 below) or there is a delay in response (example 2), or the amount of delay in response differs across VAR model equations.

I will give examples of zero restrictions, but the general argument applies to other kinds of linear or nonlinear restrictions.

**Example 1**

Suppose that the true data generating process for a bivariate time series $(y_t, x_t)$ is

$$ \begin{align}
 y_t &= a_{1,11} y_{t-1}              + a_{1,12} x_{t-1} + u_t \qquad (1) \\
 x_t &= \phantom{{}=a_{1,11} y_{t-1}}   a_{1,22} x_{t-1} + v_t \qquad (2) 
\end{align} $$

(The subscript of $a_{i,jk}$ reads as follows: $i$ stands for lag, $j$ and $k$ index the row and column of the corresponding coefficient matrix $A$ if the model is written in matrix notation.)
This could be considered a restricted VAR(1) model and written as

$$ \begin{align}
 y_t &= a_{1,11} y_{t-1}  + a_{1,12} x_{t-1} + u_t \qquad (1) \\
 x_t &= 0 \ \cdot \ \ y_{t-1} + a_{1,22} x_{t-1} + v_t \qquad (2a) 
\end{align} $$

In this system, $x$ is exogenous with respect to $y$. A *restricted* VAR model reflects the situation when the feedback between two variables goes one way but not both ways. This would not be possible in an *unrestricted* VAR model.

Now suppose you want to test whether $y$ Granger-causes $x$. Then you estimate the *unrestricted* model as well as the *restricted* model and compare them. Thus estimation of a *restricted* VAR is also instrumental in Granger causality testing.

**Example 2**

Suppose that the true data generating process for a bivariate time series $(y_t, x_t)$ is

$$ \begin{align}
 y_t &= a_{2,11} y_{t-2} + a_{2,12} x_{t-2} + u_t \qquad (3) \\
 x_t &= a_{2,21} y_{t-2} + a_{2,22} x_{t-2} + v_t \qquad (4) 
\end{align} $$

This is a *restricted* VAR(2) model with $a_{1,11}=a_{1,12}=a_{1,21}=a_{1,22}=0$ (the whole first lag is missing). This happens if there is a delay in response.

Alternatively, one could have different lags in the equations for $y_t$ and in the equation for $x_t$. That could be a VAR(2) model with $a_{1,11}=a_{1,12}=a_{2,21}=a_{2,22}=0$.

After all, the main point is that some processes are better approximated by a *restricted* VAR model, and I do not see a good reason for using an *unrestricted* VAR model in such situations.

**Edit:** as pointed out by @GraemeWalsh, restrictions may be of two types: restrictions on model coefficients (such as the ones discussed above) and restrictions on the contemporaneous covariance matrix of model errors. The latter would be considered in the context of structural vector autoregressions (SVAR) which I have limited experience with; I will not try my luck in expanding on it further.

Comment: The focus here is applying constraints to the coefficient matrix, which kind of back tracks on the argument against "incredible identifying restrictions" - thus it's more usual to think of restrictions on a VAR being imposed on the error structure. As a suggestion, it might be useful to add to this answer restrictions on the covariance matrix of the errors. The OP isn't specific about which restrictions are of interest, so this is just a thought. For example, "why add constraints to a VAR model?" could be interpreted as "why build a structural model?" or "why build an SVAR?".

Comment: Interesting, I totally missed this possibility. Somehow restricted VAR does not naturally remind me of SVAR. But once you mentioned it, I cannot disagree. However, I have limited experience with SVAR, and I am not sure if I can say anything valuable related to SVAR in this case...

Comment: I think mentioning the two types of restrictions improves the, already good, answer, so I vote up.